# Bitcoin lightnode not return private key for getnewaddress

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I have run a bitcoin lightnode (bitcoind)

I use `getnewaddress` for create new wallet:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress
```

This method return to me only wallet address.

How can I access to private key of this address?

Comment: What do you mean by "lightnode"?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I don't use fullnode.

Comment: @user140323 Bitcoin Core (bitcoind) only supports full node operation.